# Images inside Paginator in Angular 8

Tags: angular8

Does anybody know how to put images inside a paginator ?
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v8.2.9-lts/#/paginator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
**Instead of this** :

<div class="sticky-header">
  <div class="p-grid p-align-center" style="color: #007ad9;">
    <!--<div class="p-col-2 p-hidden-sm-down">
      Help Step
    </div>-->
    <p-dataView [value]="helps" [paginator]="true" [rows]="1">
      <ng-template let-help pTemplate="listItem">
        <div>
          {{help.Title}}
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-dataView>
    
  </div>
  <div class="p-grid p-align-center" class="p-col-12" style="color: #007ad9;">    
          **<img src="/assets/images/Language.jpg" alt="Trash Button">**
  </div>
    <hr />
  </div>

Use this :

<div class="sticky-header">
  <div class="p-grid p-align-center" style="color: #007ad9;">
    <!--<div class="p-col-2 p-hidden-sm-down">
      Help Step
    </div>-->
    <p-dataView [value]="helps" [paginator]="true" [rows]="1">
      <ng-template let-help pTemplate="listItem">
        <div>
          {{help.Title}}
          **<img src="/assets/images/Language.jpg" alt="Trash Button">**
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-dataView>
    
  </div>
  <div class="p-grid p-align-center" class="p-col-12" style="color: #007ad9;">
    
  </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
```

Comment: Currently the paginator lays on the bottom of my image and text. How do I place it on top of both the image and text ? (with bothe image and text inside it) ?